# Do Play! 2 Action.async requests kill the future in the background when interrupted?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.0, future

I've got the following Play! 2 `Action.async` controller:

```
def complexAlgorithm(graphId: String) = Action.async { implicit request =>
    val f = future {
      val data = new ComplexAlgorithm(GraphContext.get(graphId))
      data.evaluate
      data
    }
    f.map { result => Ok(Json.generate(result.getRankings.toList.filterNot(o => o.rankScore == 0))) }
  }
```

I've realized that in some cases this computation is actually going to take more than an hour. Since this will be redesigned for production use, I'm OK with waiting for the result in the browser since it's logged anyways.

So my question is does the future above `val f` get killed if the browser request is interrupted? Say for instance, if the internet disconnects while waiting for a response? Or will it actually complete its calculation (even if hours later)?

Thanks!

Comment: Leaving Play aside for a second, you can't interrupt a future unless you kill the JVM (or the process by command line probably), futures are an abstraction of the underlying java thread logics and in java too the only thing you can do is set the interrupted flag to true, but that won't stop the thread execution.

Comment: @EndeNeu gotcha so is it safe to assume that the future above would still be calculating if the request is interrupted? Or can an interrupt flag potentially kill the thread before completion? (by the way I'm looking at a CPU profile now and it does look like it's still going after 10min if I interrupt it)

Comment: I'm not a java expert but a thread execution is not interruptable, in java you can set a boolean flag to true using `interrupt()` and then check if it's still __running__ using `isInterrupted()`, but in the end the task will keep running. I'm not sure if calling `Play.stop()` would stop the separate thread since it kills the main one, but anyway the separate thread would have then no main thread to post its result to so it wouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to stop the evaluation after calling `data.evaluate` ?